# Using Oraclize for ICO smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, oracles

What is the advantages of using Oraclize for the development of an ICO Smart contract? doesn't it just add unnecessary complexity?

Comment: What do you want to use it for?. Personally, I do find this service excessively loaded, but it works.

Comment: Well, you might want it for getting random values or external data like the price of ETH.

Comment: Sure e.g. getting data such as the price of ETH/USD and similar. However, for an ICO i feel like it adds a lot of code for little functionality, it could just be calculated to amount of tokens per eth instead of per USD and not need oracle

Comment: If you know python you can use web3.py and do that.

Comment: Well, again, it depends of what you want to do. ICOs aren't standardized.